# How to change the number of comments per page for a single node in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i would like to change the comments per page for only a single node. Let's say that the defaul number of comments per page for the content type "article" is 50 and i want change this to 10 only for the article with nid=171.

```
$node = menu_get_object('node',1); if($node && $node->nid = 171) {......}
```

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the number of comments on individual pages, I would suggest installing [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module which allow for easy creation of any lists of things, including comments. With Views, you can create a block with comments for any node and use that instead of regular comments block. 
Also, you can have several different blocks with different number of comments, and attach whatever block you want to whatever node. Using [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module would help too, it allows to assign blocks and other elements to pages with much more sophisticated controls than Drupal core block management.

Comment: That was my first idea, i created a variant of that node with page manager and panels and then i put a view of comments with a customized pager. Unfortunately i can't use this approach for other reasons. I need to achieve this without using panels. I could use a regular view block, but without using panels i don't know how to prevent the default content and comments of the node from being displayed. (the node type is a forum topic of advanced forum module).

Comment: To hide comments from being displayed on particular content type, you can edit the content type settings and set the comments to "hidden". That will affect all new nodes of this content type, but all content that was already created will have to be edited and set to comments = hidden. Then, you could add comments using blocks (generated by a view), without a need to use panels.

Answer (score 0):

Check out can this be helpful to you:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7450/comment-per-page-settings

Since it's a form you have to alter it and change comments number from code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As understand it, those examples are to change the number of comments per page for a content type and not for a single node

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution even if a bit rude. To disable the node's default comments i used a preprocess function in template.php file of my subtheme and disbled the `$content['comments']` variable used in the comment-wrapper.tpl.php template:

```
function MYSUBTHEMENAME_preprocess_comment_wrapper(&$vars){
$node = menu_get_object();
if($node):
if($node->type === 'forum' && $node->nid == 171):
unset($vars['content']['comments']);
endif;
endif;
}
```

Note that i did it for comment wrapper variables/template and not for the node vfariables/template in order to unset the comments but to keep the comment form.

Then i created a view block of comments with a filter for the nid of the comment's node.
This works well for my purposes but if you find a more elegant way let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

I spent a time looking comment.module and found this in `comment_form_node_type_form_alter`

```
$form['comment']['comment_default_per_page'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Comments per page'),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_default_per_page_' . $form['#node_type']->type, 50),
      '#options' => _comment_per_page(),
    );
```

So I put that in my template.php

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
     if ($variables['node']->type == 'forum') {
         variable_set('comment_default_per_page_' . 'forum', 4);
     }
  }
}
```

It worked for me, I hope it helps.